# Is it possible to deploy a self hosted agent from Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, builds

I need to deploy a self hosted agent from Azure DevOps to on premise Hyper-V hosts. I have VMM managing the hosts. I need to complete the following:

- Deploy the VM from a base template
- Install Pre Requisites for the agent and Docker
- Docker will be available for the pipeline tasks
- Install the agent and connect to DevOps

The VM deployment could be something I kick off from VMM. Can I please have some guidance on how to approach this?

Any advice on a better approach also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you may download the build agent here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases

Then use: [Unattended config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#unattended-config)